# How to use the laravel 5.2 mimes?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

I've put the file in accordance with the validation.
But why do mimes don't work?

I have also added the ' enctype = "multipart/form-data" ' in the form

This piece of validation:

```
          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

            'nomor_kk' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,16',
            'srt_akademik' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg',


                ]);

                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    return redirect('/daftarbeasiswa')
                                ->withInput()
                                ->withErrors($validator, 'insert');
          }
```

This output:
[image]

Comment: If you try to do `dd($request->hasFile('srt_akademik'));` before the validator what does it return ?

Comment: can you send multiple file in str_akademik ?

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi right, I use multiple

Comment: @SérgioReis  before the validator I don't do return.

Comment: If you use multiple files, then it should be `'srt_akademik.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg',` i think. im saying for you to do `dd($request->hasFile('srt_akademik'));`  to check if the file reaches that point, as a debug method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple file use this

```
 'srt_akademik.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'
```